# SPARQL Querying Data Linked Between Two Separate Graphs

Tags: sparql, fuseki, stardog, federated-queries

I have a graph of `Person`s stored in a StarDog instance, and a graph of `Address`es in a Fuseki instance. One of the `Person` instances has a `hasAddress` relationship with an `Address`.

I wish to make a SPARQL query that simply returns all the `Person`s who have an address, as well as the address at which they live. This query is going to sent to the StarDog instance (the endpoint with the `Person` graph). The query I am using is

```
prefix testOnt: <http://www.example.org/test-ontology#>

SELECT ?person ?address 
WHERE {
  ?person testOnt:hasAddress ?address
}
```

However, this returns no results.

I am initialising the StarDog database using this bit of TTL:

```
:SomeDude rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :Person;
    :hasAddress :Address1.
```

Where `Address1` is defined in the TDB on the Fuseki side.

I just don't know how I'm meant to reference the second graph when I make a query to the other.

Thanks for any help, and I can clarify any points in the comments.

Comment: The question should be more "between two different triple stores resp. SPARQL endpoints"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query to retrieve just `?person testOnt:hasAddress ?address` should work against Stardog but would not return address information stored in Fuseki. If this query is not working then make sure the namespaces you use in the data and the query match.

In order to get people instances from Stardog and their addresses from Fuseki you will need a [federated SPARQL query](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-federated-query-20130321/#service) that uses the `SERVICE` keyword. Assuming namespaces are correct, your query should look like this:

```
prefix testOnt: <http://www.example.org/test-ontology#>

SELECT ?person ?address 
WHERE {
  ?person testOnt:hasAddress ?address
  SERVICE <http://fuseki/location> {
     ?address ?p ?o     # use a more specific BGP here if necessary
  }
}
```